# Facebook SEO with image not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

I've got an app recently put online. On my Facebook wall, when I type in the URL to my app. Facebook displays available thumbnails. At the moment it's displaying GoDaddy's thumbnails. I'm guessing its because Facebook is caching the images.

So I read somewhere about putting `image_src` on the `<head>` element. In Rails 3.1 should it be:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://www.site_name.com/assets/logo.png" />
```

Or:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="/assets/logo.png" />
```

And is using `<link rel="image_src"` the right meta tag to show the right thumbnail on Facebook? If so, do I have to wait a few hours until the thumbnail displays on Facebook?

**EDIT**

I have:

```
  <meta property="og:title" content="<%= yield(:title).present? ? yield(:title) : 'Foobar' %>" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="<%= request.url %>" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.foobar.com/assets/logo.png" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Foobar" />
```

The [Facebook debug page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) shows an actual image for `og:image`. But when I type the site's url on a wall, the thumbnail still doesn't appear

Comment: That should be working, if you share the link, does it not use the image that the debug page is detecting? it should be

Comment: That's the thing. It shows everything, except the thumbnail. The debug page shows the image though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to supply metadata to Facebook is using Open Graph tags.

The main documentation is at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

If you just want to get something set up quickly, use the form at 'Step 2' on the [Like Button documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) which will produce a set of meta tags to put in to the `<head></head>` part of your page

Comment: Do these take affect immediately?

Comment: Run the URL through the debug tool at : http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and it will clear the cache Facebook has of your page - they should take effect after that

Comment: Ahhh, I just realized. The image needed to be at least 50px x 50px